# I have a string which is '3050070202_Level2'. I want to remove the '_Level2'. As in, my desired output is just '3050070202'

Tags: python, string, split

```
input = '3050070102_Level2'

desired _output = '3050070202'
```

I tried using the `str.strip()`, but doing so will remove the 2 from the desired output as well

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove part of the string using Regex in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54384039/remove-part-of-the-string-using-regex-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
desired_output = input.split("_")[0]
```

The `split()` function splits your string at the given character sequence (in this case of length 1 and just the character `_`) and returns a list of splits. With `[0]` you index the first split which is your desired string.

Bonus: If you want to convert the resulting string to an `int` do this:

```
output_int = int(desired_output)
```